# How to dynamically modify a measure previously made by a measure control?

Tags: openlayers

Using OpenLayers 4.6.5, I've created a map with a custom measure tool with draw, modify, select and snap interactions based on [Openlayers examples](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/) and [qgis2web](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/tree/v2.34.0) code.

See this codepen https://codepen.io/agiudiceandrea/pen/xeEbzv

```js
var draw;
function addDrawInteraction() {
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: measureSource,
    type: 'Polygon'
    // a style: ...//
  });

  var listener;
  draw.on('drawstart',
    function(evt) {
      selectAltClick.getFeatures().clear();
      sketch = evt.feature;
      var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
      listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
        var geom = evt.target;
        var output;
        output = formatArea((geom));
        tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
        measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
        measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
      });
    }, this);
  draw.on('drawend',
    function(evt) {
      measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
      measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
      sketch = null;
      measureTooltipElement = null;
      createMeasureTooltip();
      ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
    }, this);
}
```

The modify and select interactions should be used to select a previously created measure polygon and then modify it updating its displayed measure value.

```js
function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip hidden';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}
```

I cannot figure out how to make the measure value for the selected measure polygon change accordingly to the new modified polygon surface area.

Could somebody give me some tips?

EDIT:

With a custom Modify interaction (mimicking the custom Draw interaction), **now I've managed to create a new measure tool tip each time I modify a previously created measure polygon** (see this new codepen https://codepen.io/agiudiceandrea/pen/xeEEox), but...
**how can I delete the previously created measure tool tip related to that polygon?**

```js
var modifyInteraction;
function addModifyInteraction() {
  modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectAltClick.getFeatures(),
  });

  var listener;
  modifyInteraction.on('modifystart',
      function(evt) {
        sketch = evt.features.item(0);
        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
        listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
          var geom = evt.target;
          var output;
          output = formatArea((geom));
          tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
          measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
          measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
        });
      }, this);
  modifyInteraction.on('modifyend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        sketch = null;
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
      }, this);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting  `evt.feature.on('change:geometry', ...);` in the `drawend`?

Comment: Thanks @Mike I've made some progress by customising the Modify interaction on modifystart and modifyend events.See the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to solve the problem by myself...
The trick was to assign a unique progressive id to the measure polygon and also the same id to the measure tooltilp overlay.
Then it's possible to retrieve and modify the previously created measure tooltip by the id of the select measure polygon.

Relevant modification are in the draw and modify interactions and createMeasureTooltip() function.
See this codepen https://codepen.io/agiudiceandrea/pen/GLjWro

```js
var draw;
function addDrawInteraction() {
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: measureSource,
    type: 'Polygon'
    // a style: ...//
  });

  var listener;
  draw.on('drawstart',
      function(evt) {
      //[...]unchanged
      }, this);

  draw.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        evt.feature.setId(measureIndex++); //adding an index to the measure polygon
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        sketch = null;
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
      }, this);
}

var modifyInteraction;
function addModifyInteraction() {
  modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectAltClick.getFeatures(),
  });

  var listener;
  modifyInteraction.on('modifystart',
      function(evt) {
        sketch = evt.features.item(0);
        modifiedMeasureIndex = sketch.getId(); //retrieves the id of measure polygon to be modified
        measureTooltip = map.getOverlayById(modifiedMeasureIndex); //the related measure tooltip overlay...
        measureTooltipElement = measureTooltip.getElement(); //...and measure tooltip Element
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure'; //apply the tooltip-measure stile

        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

        listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
        //[...]unchanged
        });
      }, this);

  modifyInteraction.on('modifyend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        sketch = null;
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        measureTooltip = map.getOverlayById(measureIndex); //restores the new overlay yet created...
        measureTooltipElement = measureTooltip.getElement(); //...and the related Element...
        //createMeasureTooltip(); //...so we can avoid to create a new one
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
      }, this);
}
```

```js
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    id: measureIndex, //ads an index to the measure tooltip overlay
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}
```